# Closing XamTabControl Tabs Using MVVM & Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism, infragistics

I am a bit stuck trying to get tabs to close with XamTabControl using MVVM. When I click the X on the tab I want it to use my DelegateCommand to run a method on my view model which removes the tab from my ObservableCollection. I'm currently using a EventTrigger to attempt to use the TabItemEx.Closed event but all that happens when I close the tab is that it's removed from the view and not from the collection of tabs on my view model. The binding of my command is not working at all, it nor the method associated with it are ever called. How do I bind to a command on my view model so I can run a method on my view model when a tab is closed?

```
<igWindows:XamTabControl Name="AttachmentsTabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedAttachments}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAttachment}" Width="400" Height="400" TabLayoutStyle="MultiRowSizeToFit" AllowTabClosing="True" TabItemCloseButtonVisibility="Visible">
        <igWindows:XamTabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </igWindows:XamTabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <igWindows:XamTabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding AttachmentImage}" Width="300" Height="300"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </igWindows:XamTabControl.ContentTemplate>

        <behaviors:Interaction.Triggers>
            <behaviors:EventTrigger EventName="TabItemEx.Closed">
                <behaviors:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TabItemClosedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=AttachmentsTabControl, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
            </behaviors:EventTrigger>
        </behaviors:Interaction.Triggers>
    </igWindows:XamTabControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `RoutedEventTrigger` as described [here](https://joyfulwpf.blogspot.com/2009/05/mvvm-invoking-command-on-attached-event.html) and handle the `TabItemEx.Closed` attached event:

```
<behaviors:EventTrigger EventName="igWindows:TabItemEx.Closed">
```

The `EventTrigger` class in `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll` doesn't support attached events.